# "maximum recursion depth exceeded" when subclassing pandas.Index

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, series

I'm getting an error if using a subclass of `pd.Index` which contains non-primitive values. I'm using `pandas 0.13.1`.

A quick demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd

class MyIndex(pd.Index): pass
# MyIndex = pd.Index  <-- if not subclassing, no problem

o1 = object(); o2 = object()  # <-- if using primitives, no problem
j = MyIndex([ o1, o2 ])
i = pd.Index(j)
j2 = MyIndex([ o2 ])
i2 = pd.Index(j2)

try:
    print pd.Series([ 4,5 ], index = j)[j2]  # <-- RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
except RuntimeError, e:
    print e
print pd.Series([ 4,5 ], index = j)[i2]  # <-- works as expected
print pd.Series([ 4,5 ], index = i)[j2]  # <-- works as expected
```

Questions:

1. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
2. What is the best way to fix/bypass this error, while still (a) using a **subclass** of `pd.Index` (my subclass includes an extended interface), and (b) contains **non-primitive** values (objects of a user-defined class).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fairly old version of pandas (current is 0.15.2). So `Index` is ultimately a sub-class of `ndarray` a pretty inflexible class to sub-class. Pandas changes to NOT sub-class this in 0.15.0.

Not sure of your goals here. Using a custom object index is pretty tricky to get right. Pandas has a new index type coming up in 0.16.0 (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8707)), as well as a whole panopoly of indexes that represent various types. Storing objects is not performant at all and is likely to cause great pain.

If you simply want to expand some aspect of custom usability it *might* be more ameanable to simple do [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation).

Comment: I see it is only 10 month old. When working on a big complex system, it is too risky and time consuming to upgrade to a new version so frequently. I *do* appreciate the pace in which pandas is improving and evolving (seriously, it's awesome), but unfortunately, I can't afford to upgrade so frequently.